Ruby On Rails - Google Cloud Speech to Text Synchronous issue
I have a ruby on rails web app and I would like to incorporate Google's Cloud Speech to Text API. This is what I have written so far:
Stimulus (just portion of the code):
  connect() {
    this.audioChunks = [];
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then((stream) => {
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });
    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
      this.audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });
    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(this.audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
      this.audioChunks.length = 0;

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('files', audioBlob);
      const url = <url_for_post>;

      const crsfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").content;
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': crsfToken,
          Accept: 'text/vnd.turbo-stream.html',
        },
        body: formData,
      })

The model for the Speech to Text:
require "google/cloud/speech/v1"

module Google
  class Speech
    def initialize
      credentials = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:google_crendentials)

      @speech_client = ::Google::Cloud::Speech::V1::Speech::Client.new do |config|
        config.credentials = credentials
      end

      diarization_config = ::Google::Cloud::Speech::V1::SpeakerDiarizationConfig.new(
        enable_speaker_diarization: true,
        min_speaker_count: 2,
        max_speaker_count: 10
      )

      @config = {
        language_code: "en-US", # Primary language code, can be set to a common language or user preference
        enable_separate_recognition_per_channel: true,
        enable_automatic_punctuation: true,
        enable_word_time_offsets: true,
        diarization_config: diarization_config
      }
    end

    def speech_to_text(audio_file)
      audio = { content: audio_file }
      response = @speech_client.recognize config: @config, audio: audio
      output_text = []
      if response.present?
        response.results.each do |obj|
          obj.alternatives.each do |alternative|
            output_text << alternative.transcript
          end
        end
      end
      output_text.compact.reject(&:empty?).join(" ")
    end
  end
end

The idea is that when a user speaks on a microhpone, the code will then convert the spoken audio to text via the synchronous recognition method. The stimulus code above basically converts the audio from the microphone and then send the blob to the Rails controller for processing via AJAX call. According to the google's documentation, https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas, the limit for a synchronous recognition is 1 minute of audio length, and 10 MB of audio file size. It works fine when I try to speak continuously for say, 20 seconds but if I try to speak continuously for anything beyond that (for example 30 seconds) it will return me an error "Sync input too long" (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/error-messages).
The thing is, when I check on the audio length and the duration when such error occurs, they did not exceed the limit that were specified in the documentation. How do I fix this such that I am able to speak continuously for up to 1 minute while still being able to convert the speech to text using the synchronous recognition? I do not want to use asynchronous recognition and other options for various reasons.
EDIT: Upon further testing, I realize I can only speak up to 29s. So as long as it is 30s or above, it will return me the error. I am suspecting it could be due to encoding format that I set in the stimulus (such as Opus in WebM) which has a higher sample rate (like 48000 Hz). I am wondering which encoding format that could support lower sample rate and also supported for all web browsers.

Does this link1 and link2 helps you?
